# Selenium Cant find element inside Iframe event tho they are visible

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe

I have been trying to create code to automatically log in into the website of a game I play called Life is Feudal to gather some information(Everything is legal, I have manually access to the informations I want but it would take years to gather everything).

So here's my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String Url = "https://lifeisfeudal.com/";
    String email = "MYEMAIL";
    String password = "MYPASSWORD";

    WebDriver driver = setDriver();

    // Open Life is feudal home page
    driver.get(Url);

    /*
     * Logging into my account
     */

    // Click on sign in button [WORK]
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();

    //Focus the Iframe
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("signin")));

    /*
     * Type in Email
     */

    //Try #1 using name (DONT WORK)
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(email);
    //Try #2 using xpath (DONT WORK)
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-view\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/input")).sendKeys(email);

    /*
     * Type in Password
     */

    //Try #1 using name (DONT WORK)
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);

    //Try #2 using xpath (DONT WORK)
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-view\"]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys(password);

    /*
     * Click the sign in button
     */

    //Try (Havent tried it yet)
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();


    //Bring back to default
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    //Rest of the code
}
```

And here's the html code inside the Iframe
[HTML Iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s35I.png)

**Edit 1:** Adding a thread.sleep(3000) after switching frame as suggested by Frank made it work.

I assume it wasnt fully loading the frame and was trying to access something not fully loading that wasnt existing at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Thread.Sleep(3000) after switching to the IFrame to figure out if it's a matter of timing. If so replace the Thread.Sleep(3000) with a more robust way of waiting like Explicit Wait.